# How to make Gpay QR Scanner corner style in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

**How to create Gpay Qr scanner style look like same**[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: want to create corner style look like gpay

Comment: Yes but what have you done yet, share your code

Comment: You could start researching [PreviewView](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview) and then make a combination with your custom overlay on the framelayout

Comment: i plan to make this, but no idea how to done this- Sniffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below XML code

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**-> Main XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_ll_layout_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_sv_camera_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#AC000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_rgb_scan"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_radius" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Scan a QR code"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dialog_close_dark" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_offline_bolt_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cast_ic_expanded_controller_mute" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**-> drawable-corner_radius:**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >
    <solid
        android:color="#33FFFFFF" >
    </solid>
    <corners
        android:radius="15dp"   >
    </corners>
</shape>
```

**->**[drwabale: corner_rgb_scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KTNN.png)

**The theme for fullscreen (ManifestFile: android:theme="@style/FullScreen")**

```
<style name="FullScreen" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```